# How to calculate Shannon diversity by factor levels in r

Tags: r

I am a newbie with R. I have a large dataset (66M obs) with pixel temperature data of 4 water bodies (REF,LMB, OTH, FP) at hourly time steps (6am,7am,8am...), with several NA values illustrating blank pixels. I want to calculate a proxy for temperature heterogeneity/diversity for each water body at each time, by using Shannon Diversity or other similar indexes. I have so far managed to calculate basic stats using an available online source, but not sure how to apply more specific diversity indexes.

My data looks like:
[First column Temp, second Time, third water](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLWav.png)

My code:

DF<-read.csv("DF_total.csv",stringsAsFactors = T)

levels(DF$water)

[1]"OTH" "LMB" "REF" "FP"

levels(DF$time)
NULL

source("group_by_summary_stats.R")[**]

summary<-group_by_summary_stats(DF, Temp ,water ,time)

[**]source found online

Comment: Refer on how to ask reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Done, see edited version, thanks!